# Location of diffraction pattern on the image plane/detector plane

Tags: experimental-physics, diffraction, imaging

I am trying to make a spectrometer. At the moment, I have an optical setup consisting of a laser, diffraction grating and a screen/detector in a straight line. I am trying to understand how to estimate the location of the diffraction pattern of the source on the screen? Is it the same location on the screen as the location of the laser/source?

Comment: *I am trying to understand how to estimate the location of the diffraction pattern of the slit on the screen?* - Which slit?

Comment: With the grating parameters and the known laser wavelength, the angles of the diffraction orders vs angle of incidence are straightforward to calculate, then use ray-tracing.

Comment: My apologies for mentioning slit. At the moment there is no slit, it is just the laser. The question that I am trying to answer is where to should I place the sensor to collect the diffraction pattern. Since the source can be different, how should I calculate the location of the diffraction pattern on the screen to place the linear CCD array at the right location to collect the pattern. Apologies for confusion.